# Money exchange best value for a new middle-aged traveller

Tags: international-travel, money, exchange

I'm travelling to Thailand in September and would like to know if is it better for me to change money here in Australia before I go or when I get to the airport in Bangkok.

If here where would be the best place to get better value?

Comment: Where does the middle aged part enter?

Answer (score 3):

When I traveled to Thailand some years back, I found the best deals where in country!  Find a big bank and you will find the best rates, just be cautious about hawkers vending out of date currency! I still have an envelope with a few of the bills I could not exchange back to US currency. They were out of date or fake.

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't matter as long as a bank in Australia has decent rates.
If you decide to do that in Thailand, I suggest you to change a little amount in Australia still and then when you arrive, change the rest in Bangkok because in the airport the rates might not be good.

I recommend Bangkok bank.